Mage cannot connect to Postgresql hosted in docker
Here my docker compose file
version: '3'
services:
  magic:
    image: mageai/mageai:latest
    command: mage start ${PROJECT_NAME}
    env_file:
      - .env
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      ENV: dev
      USER_CODE_PATH: /home/src/${PROJECT_NAME}
      POSTGRES_DBNAME: ${POSTGRES_DBNAME}
      POSTGRES_SCHEMA: ${POSTGRES_SCHEMA}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_HOST: ${POSTGRES_HOST}
      POSTGRES_PORT: ${POSTGRES_PORT}
    ports:
      - 6789:6789
    volumes:
      - .:/home/src/
      - ~/Documents/secrets/personal-gcp.json:/home/src/personal-gcp.json
    restart: on-failure:5
  postgres:
    image: postgres:14
    restart: on-failure
    container_name: ${PROJECT_NAME}-postgres
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DBNAME}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - "${POSTGRES_PORT}:5432"
  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=admin@admin.com
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=root
    ports:
      - "8080:80"


and this is my .env file
PROJECT_NAME=magic-zoomcamp
POSTGRES_DBNAME=postgres
POSTGRES_SCHEMA=magic
POSTGRES_USER=postgres
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
POSTGRES_HOST=postgres
POSTGRES_PORT=5432

i try to connect to the Postgres by running
(https://i.sstatic.net/M6b29VKp.png)
but got these error every time.
(https://i.sstatic.net/AJp0TTw8.png)
how can i solve this?
i hope i will know the root cause of problem that i facing

You have to set env var to connect into database , here is corrected properties:
  POSTGRES_CONNECT_TIMEOUT: 10
  POSTGRES_DBNAME: "{{ env_var('POSTGRES_DBNAME') }}"
  POSTGRES_USER: "{{ env_var('POSTGRES_USER') }}"
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "{{ env_var('POSTGRES_PASSWORD') }}"
  POSTGRES_HOST: "{{ env_var('POSTGRES_HOST') }}"
  POSTGRES_PORT: "{{ env_var('DB_PORT') }}"

you need to configure it in io_config.yaml file

It work now. Thank a lot!!
